# How can I passing array in javascript to php - LARAVEL?

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

My controller as below;

```
public function edit($id) {
$get_property = StockPropertyTemplate::where('group_id' , $id)->where('type' , 'property')->get();

 //like get_property = ['1' , '2' , '3'];
 return view('eticaret.property_groups.edit' , compact('get_property'));
}
```

My edit.blade as below;

```
@extends('layouts.app_master')
    @section('content')
    {--this part is not important--}
    @endsection 
    @section('footer')
     <script>
            var getProperty = {!! $get_property !!}
            alert(getProperty);
        </script>
    @endsection
```

How can i get output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should do `json_encode`

```
var getProperty = {!! json_encode($get_property) !!}
```